# Positioning the DIV at correct position

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I am new to CSS and have been trying lately to position the DIV where I wish too, but some properties like float and margin and confusing me. In the image below I am trying to place the white div to the right of the logo.

Since I am not able to post pictures yet on the post, I uploaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xdZJ.jpg)

Html :

```
<body>

<header>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>

        <nav>
            <div class="navigation">

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>    

</header>

</body>
```

css :

```
.header {
    max-width:1200px;
    min-width:200px;
    height:170px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius:3px;

}

.logo {
    width:230px;
}

.logo img {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:31px;
    border-right:solid  #FFF 1px;
    padding-right:33px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;

}


.navigation {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:200px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below **.logo img** and **.navigation** with your CSS with this, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJLC6/1/)

```
.logo img {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:31px;
    border-right:solid  #FFF 1px;
    padding-right:33px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}


.navigation {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:31px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;

}
```

- place **float:left;** in your **.logo img {...}** class
- place **margin-top:31px;** in your **.navigation {...}** class

Answer (score 1):

Change `.navigation`'s `position:fixed;` to `position:inline-block`; and add `margin-top` to make them in line vertically depending on how tall each is

Or you could `float:left;` both of them